# MS365, Excel 13 - New row added not auto updating formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a table in Excel I made myself not an inserted one - though I have tried that too it didn't do anything. The problem is at the end I add a new row and none of my formulas are in the new row. My automatic update is on, I have used a table nothing is making it have my formulas in the new row. they are all blank,

I have about 15 columns and most are simple formulas like add and divide however some are make complicated such as Vlookups and nested functions and arrays etc the only cell in my new row that did update it the cell i have data validation in with a list of names, below is a picture of my last days entries,

[image]

...then a picture of new inserted rows,

[image]

I then took an example pic of K10 formula bar,

[image]

...and the new K11 that was added with NO formula at all.

[image]

You can also see if doesn't add my borders, the only auto I get is the fill color. It is currently NOT in a table but I assure you I have already tried that and it didn't change anything so I converted back to a range.

Once again is it NOT in a TABLE: So for those that think that is the solution or did not ready my previous sentences... Here is another picture of my data interested as a TABLE and then a picture of new rows WITH NO FORMULAS(in this photo the formula bar is showing E12)

[image]

[image]

Comment: So is it a [[table]] or just cells?

Comment: It is NOT a table. I have done that - it did not change the updating.

Comment: So why *would* it auto-fill your formulas in new blank rows?

Comment: If you can not help please don't comment.

Comment: I'm asking a question that demands an answer to be able to help you. Excel doesn't auto-fill after the fact unless there's something set up to make it do so. But, you know, [I probably can't help](http://superuser.com/help/badges/205/microsoft-excel?userid=116196). So, you know, [I'll move on](http://superuser.com/help/badges/157/worksheet-function?userid=116196).

Comment: You are describing capital-t Table behavior.  Like @Raystafarian, I don't understand why you are expecting to get the behavior of a Table (autofilling formulas) without having a Table.  Excel doesn't do that.

Comment: As far as I remember, once you insert new rows in Excel you don't actually get cells auto-filled with contiguous formulas, you will need to "manually" do a copy/paste, better if you *paste-special:formula*... just my 2c.

Comment: I see your screen shot in which you added rows _outside_ of your Table, and they were not treated like they were part of the Table.  That's because they aren't - they are after the last row.  Insert rows _inside_ the Table, and they will be part of it, and formulas will be autofilled.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with inserting a new table row and my vLookup not extending to the new row. I noticed that one of my lookups was extending while the others were not. So it got me thinking what was different then it hit me. On the first column I extended the vLookup by clicking the fill handle, while the other columns I did a copy on the first cell and pasted to all the other cells. So I went back to all the columns that were not working and used the fill handle from the first cell to extend it to the other cells and now they all work.